# Virtualenv Issue: Django Project

Tags: python, django

I had created and activated **virtualenv** and worked on my **Django Project**.
Now scene is that i've **Reinstall my Windows** 10. Now when i tried to enter **my env e.g. workon DFMS**
I face following error...

```
'workon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Or When i tried to run server using python manage.py runserver i face following issue...

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

My Question is how to activate that old virtualenv for that project? and how to resolve this problem?
Thank You.

Comment: I'm not a windows user....  do you have bash shell?   There are really 3 steps to establishing. 1. install python dev env: `pip3 install virtualenv` 2. in your project dir establish venv `python3 -m venv venv`  3. assuming your have a requirements.txt install your project packages `source venv\bin\activate; pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtual environment with `virtualenv venv` and start it with `venv/bin/activate`.

make sure added the directory of your project into environment variable of your computer

> you need to run Command prompt as Administrator.